# 'MessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to handle this kind of warning

I have used

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("message data : \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
```

Comment: What's the question? FCM direct channel was [deprecated in Firebase iOS SDK 6.18.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6180_-_february_25_2020). It will be removed in Firebase 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321313/update-deprecated-firebase-functions-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to use  `remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage` ?

In my case, on the `MessagingDelegate`, the only thing I need is to get the fcmToken (Firebase Registration Token), I completely remove the `remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage`

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        
        firebaseData.fcmToken = fcmToken
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: Then where/How you will get Data Messages now?