# Update deprecated Firebase functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I have this code to push app notifications.
It works well but I get this warning:
**'MessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling.**
and this one **'appData' is deprecated**

I made a research on Google but didn't find anything to fix this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
              application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
         
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
         
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        return true
    }
    
    // The callback to handle data message received via FCM for devices running iOS 10 or above.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079361/messagingremotemessage-is-deprecated-fcm-direct-channel-is-deprecated-please

Comment: @Rob I already saw this answer but couldn't figure out how it could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether you are simply sending display/alert notifications and background notifications? Or are you using direct channel to send some hidden data message for real time updates?

MessagingRemoteMessage is data message object sent and handled through direct channel. If you only want to push notifications, and you also don't seem to enable direct channel in your code above. You can use Apple's API UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to handle alert message or AppDelegate `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` to handle background notifications.