# FCM - Cannot find type 'MessagingRemoteMessage' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the code I use in my AppDelegate in order to receive messages in iOS:

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    
    let dataDict:[String: String?] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
  }

  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
  }
}
```

I have recently started getting this error message after compiling:

```
Cannot find type 'MessagingRemoteMessage' in scope
```

which makes the build fail.

What should I do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessagingRemoteMessage` was removed from Firebase in the 7.0.0 release.

More info at [Update deprecated Firebase functions in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321313/update-deprecated-firebase-functions-in-swift)

Comment: So can I just remove those lines? Should I replace them with something else?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client