# Cannot find type 'MessagingRemoteMessage' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to get InApp messages using firebase but this error appears every time I write the firebase function.

```
public func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    if let apsDic = remoteMessage.appData as? [String:Any] {
        EngagementMessage.sharedInstance.presentEngagementCompaign(data: apsDic)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HycQ.png)

Comment: Seems like `MessagingRemoteMessage` is deprecated. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079361/messagingremotemessage-is-deprecated-fcm-direct-channel-is-deprecated-please

Comment: Yes it is deprecated and it ask to use APNs downstream , how to get InApp messages now with version 7 of firebase.

Comment: Show all relevant lines of code.  Showing only several lines is not going to help anyone to identify your issue.